# Configurar Uso de Memoria MySQL

Tags: mysql, memória

Tenho um servidor Windows Server 2012, com 24GB de RAM, Processador AMD FX 6100 com 6 núcleos.

Gostaria de configurar o MySQL para melhor desempenho de leitura e de importação de bases, alguém pode me ajudar  a configurar corretamente?

Já li sobre o assunto em diversos lugares mas não achei nenhuma explicação de acordo com a quantidade de memória existente.